# pagination bootstrap in codeigniter can't show other page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, pagination

i try to make pagination using bootstrap in codeigniter. Pagination show in my view. But, when i want to go to other page, i got 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found. What's wrong ?

This is my controller

```
public function shop($page = 'shop', $offset = 0) {
    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
    // breadcrumb start
    $breadcrumb = array(
        "Beranda" => "index",
        "Belanja Sekarang" => "",
    );
    $data['breadcrumb'] = $breadcrumb;
    // breadcrumb end

    // pagination start
    $jml = $this->db->get('produk');
    $num_rows = $this->db->count_all("produk");

    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . "page/shop";
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows;
    $config['per_page'] = 9;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['offset'] = $offset;

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
    $offset = $page == 0 ? 0 : ($page - 1) * $config["per_page"];

    // memanggil method di model
    $data['produk'] = $this->cart_model->retrieve_products($config['per_page'], $page);

    $this->load->view('user/templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('user/templates/navigation', $data);
    $this->load->view('user/pages/' . $page, $data);
    $this->load->view('user/templates/footer', $data);
}
```

this is my model

```
class Cart_model extends CI_Model {
// Our Cart_model class extends the Model class
// Function to retrieve an array with all product information
function retrieve_products($num, $offset) {
    $query = $this->db->get('produk', $num, $offset); // Select the table products
    return $query->result_array(); // Return the results in a array.
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a bad url for a start `&=9` is not a valid url parameter, the first one should start with `?` and be followed by an identifying key. `shop?offset=9`. But in this case Alghi Fari answered the question, the url you're looking for is `page/shop/9`

Comment: what you check by offset??

Comment: so, what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

that was wrong on url:

thats url is : **http://localhost/sjpro/page/shop&=9**

true : **http://localhost/sjpro/page/shop/9**

from function

```
public function shop($page = 'shop', $offset = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

**in Controller**

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . "page/shop";
$config['total_rows'] = $num_rows;
$config['per_page'] = 9;
$config['uri_segment'] = 2;
$limit =  $config['per_page'];

// boostrap Pagination. Just import boostrap. This will take CSS code automatically
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['last_link'] = false;
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

$data['produk'] = $this->cart_model->retrieve_products($limit, $page);

$this->load->view('user/templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('user/templates/navigation', $data);
$this->load->view('user/pages'. $data);
$this->load->view('user/templates/footer', $data);
```

**in Model**

```
class Cart_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function retrieve_products($limit , $page)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM produk LIMIT $page,$limit ");
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**in view**

```
foreach ( $produk as $new_produk )
{
  //This should be your data base fields
    echo $new_produk['database field1'];
    echo $new_produk['database field2'];
}
```

end of the main div just echo the link(pagination with boostrap style)

```
    <?$php    
    echo $links;//This create your pagination.
    ?>
```